# How to pass a JS object from a <tr>'s double-click listener to a <button>'s click listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, materialize

[**JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/07sp477w/)

```js
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();

$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
  edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
  closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
  draggable: true, // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
    onOpen: function(el) {
    alert("Drawer opened");//check
  },
  onClose: function(el) { 
    alert("Drawer closed");//check
  }
});






$("button").click(function() {
  alert("Here I need to send the JS object named 'data' in the dblclick() listener, to the server, in an AJAX request. THE QUESTION IS how do I get that 'data' from the dblclick() listener to here?");
});










$("table tr.table-row").dblclick(function(e) {
  var values = $(e.target).parent().text().split('\n');
  var keys = $('thead').text().split('\n');
  var processed_keys = new Array();
  var processed_values = new Array();
  var data = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    if(keys[i].trim() !== ""){
      processed_keys.push(keys[i].trim());
    }
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i].trim() !== ""){
      processed_values.push(values[i].trim());
    }
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < processed_keys.length; i++){
    data[processed_keys[i]] = processed_values[i];
  }

  console.log(data);
  alert("Following is the dataset that needs to be sent to the click listener of the button");
  alert(data);
  
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>







<section id="slide-out" class="side-nav blue-grey lighten-4"><button>Send AJAX request</button></section>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse" style="display:none;"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>








<table class="responsive-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Place</td>
    <td>Animal</td>
    <td>Thing</td>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Berlin</td>
    <td>Mouse</td>
    <td>TV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Luke</td>
    <td>Munich</td>
    <td>Giraffe</td>
    <td>Radio</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

There is an HTML `<table`. When a user double-clicks its row `<tr>`, a `dblclick()` listener is invoked. In this listener, I retrieve the data from the row clicked in the form of key-value pairs (i.e. a JS object). Let's call this JS object **`Dataset A`**. Also, in this listener, a side-drawer is opened, in which there is a button.

This is what I need:

When a user clicks the aforementioned button, it should send the **`Dataset A`** in an AJAX request to the server. The question is, how will the button's click listener get this **`Dataset A`**?

**My question is, how do I pass the `Dataset A` from the `dblclick()` listener of `<tr>` to the `onclick()` listener of the button, so that I can send it in an AJAX request to the server?**

Comment: You could create a global variable and place the object in there. Then in the click handler check if the variable is set and if it is, send it using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are in the same page, save the item somewhere in a var and use it in the button - for example move the `var data;` to outside the function and use `data = {};` in the dblclick or use sessionStorage

Also only have ONE set of jQuery script

```js
var data;
$(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

  $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
    menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
    edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
    draggable: true, // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
    onOpen: function(el) {
      alert("Drawer opened"); //check
    },
    onClose: function(el) {
      alert("Drawer closed"); //check
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });

  $("table tr.table-row").dblclick(function(e) {
    var values = $(e.target).parent().text().split('\n');
    var keys = $('thead').text().split('\n');
    var processed_keys = new Array();
    var processed_values = new Array();
    data = {}; // initialise

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (keys[i].trim() !== "") {
        processed_keys.push(keys[i].trim());
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i].trim() !== "") {
        processed_values.push(values[i].trim());
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < processed_keys.length; i++) {
      data[processed_keys[i]] = processed_values[i];
    }

    console.log(data);
    alert("Following is the dataset that needs to be sent to the click listener of the button\n"+JSON.stringify(data));

    $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="slide-out" class="side-nav blue-grey lighten-4"><button>Send AJAX request</button></section>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse" style="display:none;"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Place</td>
      <td>Animal</td>
      <td>Thing</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Berlin</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td>TV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>Luke</td>
      <td>Munich</td>
      <td>Giraffe</td>
      <td>Radio</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- A Number Of Rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```